# Recent commenting activity in 'Moderation Tools' is not by commenting date, rather post date, so it doesn't show if post is old

Tags: support, bug, moderator-tools

In the **Moderation Tools → Stats tab → Posts with notable activity →  Most commented**, recent heavy commenting activity doesn't show if the post is old, which means the tool only shows by Q/A creation (or last edit?) date, and not by commenting date (for the last 2 days for example).

I tried to search [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) to see if it's been reported / asked about before, but I had no luck.

**Example:**

Screenshots in case comments are deleted, and for you to see what I'm seeing:

The [post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11523/14897) (What happens when lightning strikes an airplane?) was last edited in 2015 (edited Jan 6 '15 at 22:03). All the comments are 2 days old (and I'm viewing last 7 days for example).

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Here on Meta, the top three under "most commented" were posted on Aug 14, Sep 4, and Aug 20.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I've added an example.